# Extract cross-sections from a DEM

Tags: qgis, dem, cross-section

I have the centerline of a river and multiple lines perpendicular to it on Qgis. I would like to extract the cross-sections in correspondence to those lines, how could I do?
I tried qprof but the .csv in output is not correct (if I try to plot it with excel it doesn't give back the section)

Comment: Old, but have you seen this question: [Extracting raster values with polylines in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114421/extracting-raster-values-with-polylines-in-qgis)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [Profile tool](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/profiletool/) which you can download from Plugin Manager. The tool can use your existing line layer to extract the profile from the raster data.

Have a look at this video: [Using the Profile Tool plugin in QGIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=UD0Oumv5y1w) which I selected randomly to show how to use Profile tool.

To use for existing vector layer:

1. Select the raster image
2. Add Layer
3. From the drop-down list select `Selected Polyline`
4. Select the line layer
5. Select the line in the map view `the one above the raster image`

[image]

It will become yellow and you can see the profile under the line:

[image]